# Calculate Count Distinct without grouped columns in Oracle

Tags: oracle, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to extract a few records and I ran into the "not a single group" error. This error can be resolved by removing the `(count(distinct dc.DUCT_FID)) as NO_OF_WAYS` column expression. However, I really need this column in my extraction.

```
SELECT TELEM.EXCH_CODE, 
       TELEM.CENTRAL_OFFICE, 
       TELEM.IPID as SEGMENT_IPID, 
       TELEM.FEATURE_STATE AS SEGMENT_STATUS,
       DCON.G3E_FID AS DUCT_FID, 
       DELEM.FEATURE_STATE AS DUCT_STATUS,
       COND.FR_MH, 
       COND.TO_MH, 
       TI.TRENCH_LENGTH, 
       (count(distinct dc.DUCT_FID)) as NO_OF_WAYS,
       TELEM.YEAR_PLACED AS YEAR_BUILD,
       ADDR.STREET_NAME AS LOCATION, 
       ADDR.POSTAL_CODE, 
       TELEM.OWNERSHIP
FROM SGTEL10.B$GC_NETELEM_0404 TELEM
JOIN SGTEL10.B$GC_COND_0404 COND ON COND.G3E_FID = TELEM.G3E_FID
JOIN SGTEL10.TRENCH_INFO TI ON TI.PIPE_FID = COND.G3E_FID 
LEFT JOIN SGTEL10.B$GC_CONTAIN_0404 FCON ON FCON.G3E_OWNERFID = TELEM.G3E_FID
LEFT JOIN SGTEL10.B$GC_CONTAIN_0404 DCON ON DCON.G3E_OWNERFID = FCON.G3E_OWNERFID
LEFT JOIN SGTEL10.B$GC_DUCT_0404 DUCT ON DUCT.G3E_FID = DCON.G3E_FID
LEFT JOIN SGTEL10.DUCT_COUNT DC ON DC.DUCT_FID = DUCT.G3E_FID
LEFT JOIN SGTEL10.B$GC_NETELEM_0404 DELEM ON DELEM.G3E_FID = DUCT.G3E_FID
LEFT JOIN SGTEL10.B$GC_ADDRESS_0404 ADDR ON ADDR.G3E_FID = COND.G3E_FID
WHERE TELEM.IPID IN (4001702,
                     4005753,
                     4005757,
                     4005785
                    );
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You use `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)` expression without `GROUP BY clause`. If you need this value for each group (if there are duplicates in your output while removing `COUNT()` expression) you must add `GROUP BY` for all other fields in output list. Or you can use the window variant of `COUNT()` function which is scalar. - [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)